# Android eBook reader with Esperanto dictionary integration

Tags: books, dictionaries

I am looking for an Android eBook reader (PDF or ePUB) that integrates with an Esperanto dictionary.

While reading I want to be able to highlight an Esperanto word and get its translation in a popup window so that I can easily continue my reading without much interruption.

Does anyone know if there is an Android app that supports this?

Comment: If Kindle will allow the download of an Esperanto dictionary, then it might be possible embedded there.  I have done that with other languages within Kindle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many readers support dictionary integration, though sometimes with clumsy invocation. After some searching, I settled on ZXReader (allows several dictionary programs and you can set it up to lookup by long tap which I prefer, though book adding is not very intuitive) and Fora dictionary (allows using your own dictionaries) and I compiled my own bilingual EO dictionary (from free sources). In the end, it works almost perfectly, though it needed some tuning. And it works offline.

Answer (score 1):

I set up Google Translate on my Android phone so that when you copy a word or phrase, the app pops up and you can translate it instantly. Your concept is even better but Translate may be a good stopgap.